# How to change value of DynamicXML in a legacy application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I am to manipulate and add a feature to a legacy application that heavily on XML and dynamic values.

I simply what to update the value if a condition is met.

```
      public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject
    {   
         XElement _root;
        private DynamicXml(XElement root)
        {
            _root = root;
        }

          public static DynamicXml Parse(string xmlString)
        {
            return new DynamicXml(RemoveNamespaces(XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root));
        }

         dynamic dynamicXML = DynamicXml.Parse(data);

           if (dynamicXML.POLICY.PARTNER == "Ecom")
              {
                 if (dynamicXML.POLICY.MARKETER == "Dressing")
                     {
                        dynamicXML.POLICY.PRICE = "1800.00";
                     }
              }
           }
```

```
<POLICY>
    <MARKETER>Dressing</MARKETER>
    <PRICE>1000.0000</PRICE>
    <PARTNER>Ecom</PARTNER>
</POLICY>
```

I keep getting {"'Middleware.Models.DynamicXml' does not contain a definition for 'PRICE'"}

Comment: Is `DynamicXml` any Microsoft .NET framework API?

Comment: What you posted doesn't compile. There's no code that actually returns any XML value.

Comment: I have updated the code with more line of code

Comment: Did that code work in some versions of .NET and doesn't work in a current? If you use XElement, why can't you use its normal API? I think the whole thing of accessing XML children as properties directly by name is a VB extension to System.Xml.Linq. I don't see how using `dynamic` in C# would enable it on XElement. Unless that `Middleware.Models.DynamicXml` does some more, heavier stuff.

Comment: The code is currently working with no problem. I need to check if the XML contains some value, then change the price if value is available

Comment: In terms of the XML structure, what seems wrong about all those paths with e.g. `dynamicXML.POLICY.PARTNER` and `dynamicXML.POLICY.MARKETER` as well as `dynamicXML.POLICY.PRICE` is that the root element is the policy element so the child is dynamicXML.PRICE in my understanding.

Comment: You are correct.